# How to block http flood connections in windows

Tags: c++

I have an application made in c ++ that acts as a server. Gameserver.exe

The problem is that they manage to attack gameserver.exe with http flood connections, for example http://ip:port

The attacks are sent from an application called "railgun"

How can I block or prevent these http connections?

Currently I use an anti flood in the gameserver.exe application which is basically this.

```
int gObjGetIPIndex(char* IpAddress)
{
    int Ret = -1;

    for (int x = 0; x < LastIPList; x++)
    {
        if (IPList[x][0] == IpAddress[0])
        {
            if (strcmp(IPList[x], IpAddress) == 0)
            {
                return x;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Ret = LastIPList;
    sprintf(IPList[LastIPList], "%s", IpAddress);
    LastIPList++;
    if (LastIPList >= 2000)LastIPList = 0;
    return Ret;
}


short gObjAdd(SOCKET socket, char* IpAddress, int aIndex) // OK stdafx.h ? 
{
    if (OBJECT_RANGE(aIndex) == 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (gObj[aIndex].Connected != OBJECT_OFFLINE)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    //========================================
    // Anti Flood Fix 13/08/2020
    //========================================

    if (gServerInfo.m_EnableAntiflood == 1)
    {
        int IPIndex = gObjGetIPIndex(IpAddress);

        DWORD CurTick = GetTickCount();

        if ((CurTick - LastConnect[IPIndex]) < 1000)
        {
            LastConnect[IPIndex] = CurTick;


            LogAdd(LOG_RED, "[AntiFlood][%d] BlockAttack (%s)", aIndex, IpAddress);

            return -1;
        }

        LastConnect[IPIndex] = CurTick;
    }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can't prevent them from the server code. Once the connections reach your code, they are already in the system. All you can do is disconnect them at the first chance you get. To really prevent them, put a flood-preventing firewall in front of your server, this is not a job for your server code to handle itself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau How can I recognize an http connection, to be able to disconnect it?

Comment: Whatever you do, your `gObjGetIPIndex` could be replaced by some sort of `map`, You could keep track of IP:s, count connection attempts, frequency etc. When an IP breaks a threshold value you can tell the OS to block traffic from that IP. address. It's better to do the blocking as far from your application as you can. If you've got a programmable router - block there.  In Windows you'd probably use Windows Firewall. In Linux I use `iptables`. Unblocking can be done based on time and also number of violations.

Comment: @theloko You would have to read the first few bytes from an accepted client to detect if it is sending an HTTP request or not. Assuming any data is being sent at all. A flooder is more likely to just connect for the sake of connecting and not send anything at all. So you would have to be prepared to handle that case, too. More likely, the flooder might not even finish the TCP handshake, thus your code wouldn't even see the connections, but your OS would and use up resources trying to handle them.

Comment: @theloko Also, if a flooder did happen to get accepted into your code, your anti-flood logic is not very robust. Multiple legit clients could come from the same IP, if they are behind a NAT. Also, when adding a new client to `IPList`, or overflowing `IPList`, you are not resetting the corresponding slot in `LastConnect`, so your `CurTick` check acts on stale data.

Comment: Can any of you help me improve my code for money in paypal? @RemyLebeau ted-lyngmo

Comment: @theloko this is a Q&A site. Please [do not solicit consulting work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329915/). You have been told what you need. If you have trouble understanding/implementing it, feel free to ask more questions about it. If you want to pay someone to fix it for you, there are other sites for that.